# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException <OR> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.shouldRunOnHWLayer Exception on my android app

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I'm getting a **java.lang.IllegalStateException  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.shouldRunOnHWLayer** on my android app I'm adding the full stacktrace below. Can anyone help me with this issue? All I can understand that this issue is happening on Android support library but how to resolve this issue.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2449)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2509) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:153)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1373)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5527)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:739)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:629)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     
           at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4310)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4146)
           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView (ViewPager.java)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4087)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4060)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.modifiesAlpha (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .shouldRunOnHWLayer (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .throwException (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .putFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .makeOpenCloseAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .makeFadeAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .loadAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .enqueueAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .allocBackStackIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .setBackStackIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .makeRemovedFragmentsInvisible (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .postponePostponableTransactions (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .completeExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .popBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .restoreAllState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .attachController (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .dispatchOnFragmentPreAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .dispatchOnFragmentCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or   .access$300 (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .execSingleAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .executePostponedTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .addAddedFragments (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .addBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .dispatchOnFragmentAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .dispatchOnFragmentActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .dispatchOnFragmentStarted (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           or .access$200 (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java)
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1238)
           at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6320)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2412)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Animators, do you? Check that you set ***Animator.AnimatorListener*** to Animator:

```
addListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener)
```

Show your code, if that does not help.